# Adding and getting Comm Ports from RXTX

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

I am currently working on a project which needs to communicate with a device connected on a commport. I have one function below which searches for serial ports, adds them to a hashmap then returns the hashmap. I noticed a problem where whenever I try to get something from the HashMap, it give a `java.lang.nullPointerException` Am I trying to get the port from the map incorrectly? Please let me know if I need to post more code.

```
private Enumeration ports = null;
public HashMap<String, CommPortIdentifier> searchForPorts() {
        ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        while (ports.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier curPort = (CommPortIdentifier) ports.nextElement();
            if (curPort.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
                System.out.println("Adding: " + curPort.getName() + "-" + curPort);  
                portMap.put(curPort.getName(), curPort);
                System.out.println(portMap.get(curPort.getName())); //works: prints out gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier@9f116cc
            }
        }
        log.fine("Successfully looked for ports");
        Iterator it = portMap.entrySet().iterator();
        String s="";
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            s = pair.getKey().toString();
            System.out.println(s); //prints out COM24 like it should
            it.remove();
        }
        System.out.println(portMap.get(s)); //Prints out null??
        return portMap;
    }
```

Portions of this code are taken from [here](https://www.henrypoon.com/blog/2011/01/01/serial-communication-in-java-with-example-program/).

Comment: you fill a map, print a text, empty the map, and then try to get an element from the map you just emptied.

Comment: @jhamon Where do I empty it? I remove the element from the Iterator, not the HashMap.

Comment: as stated in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29): Removes from the **underlying** collection the last element returned by this iterator

Comment: How do I iterate through the HashMap without removing the elements?

Comment: Check the link in my previous comment, section right over `Remove`. Hint: it's `next()`. Another solution would be to use a foreach loop instead of a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove elements in your map using `it.remove()` as it's stated in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()): Removes from the **underlying** collection the last element returned by this iterator

To access next element using an iterator you just need to use [`it.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next()) (assuming there is remaining elements).

Another solution is to use a foreach loop like this:

```
for(Map.Entry pair : portMap.entrySet()){
    s = pair.getKey().toString();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```